# Ajax Headers Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I make a request in ajax which is supposed in case of success redirected me to a link which must be returned in the return value (in the response header) and have access to this famous value the "location"

[image]

I make a request in ajax which is supposed in case of success redirected me to a link which must be returned in the return value (in the response header) and have access to this famous value the "location"

I already tried with `xhr.getResponseHeader ("location")` but nothing returns me a null.

Moreover the code that I put in `success` in my ajax request is not executed or when I put it in `complete` it is well taken into account (I checked and my `xhr.status` is 201)

I show you my request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.asaplace.v-labs.fr/users/me/cards',

    dataType: 'json',

    type: 'POST',

    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
    },

    success: function(data,status,xhr){
        if(xhr.status === 201){
            alert("fonction success");
            console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("location"));
        }

    },

    complete: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));
    },


});
```

So as I said above in the console I would have a `null` that appears but it is the `complete` and not that of `success`

I also wondered that as my site is in http and that SMoeny is in https there is maybe a problem because of that ...

And as a result, headers are similar to Basic Authentication, Bearer authentication should only be used over HTTPS (SSL).

(I also specify that this is not the status 200)

Answer (score 0):

Try using "L" instead of "l" (to uppercase):

`console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));`

See that too:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use
>   jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried with a capital L but nothing changes ...
I keep looking :)

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Try using "done" instead of "success"... check my post edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, look further down ->

Comment: The "done" is out of block, put inside the "$.ajax...".

Comment: Hi I tried the done inside the ajax but nothing either ... yet in the doc they put the .done outside the ajax it seems to me ...
I continue my research

Comment: I think we are on a bad track. At first I had more information the rental was null and I'm sure there was almost